# Unable to copy background colours in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, background, copy

Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zKC8n9CUofa5WWKjbYvKYJXTpsi9Ohb7oiu8kPQeyZM/edit?usp=sharing

I am developing a script that updates a column or inserts, deletes rows in a slave sheet called "EQUIPMENT_BOOKING"  if any rows are inserted deleted in "EQUIPMENT_MASTER" sheet or any cells are edited in a column called "Kit Description" in the "EQUIPMENT_MASTER"

All the values and formatting are correctly copied, rows are deleted and inserted where necessary to reflect the changes BUT...... I cannot get the background colours of the column "Kit Description" to copy over into column 1 of "EQUIPMENT_BOOKING"

The OnSheetChange is run by an OnChange trigger.
I am suspecting this is a permissions issue which I find absurd as I can change anything but the background colour.
Help will be greeatly appreciated after many hours and iterations/attempts at getting this to work

```js
function onSheetChange(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  // Specify the sheets you want to monitor for changes
  switch (sheetName) {
    case "EQUIPMENT_MASTER":
      handleEquipmentMasterChanges(event);
      break;
    case "SOME_OTHER_SHEET":
      // Add your code for EQUIPMENT_BOOKING changes here
      break;
    // Add more cases for other sheets you want to monitor
  }
}




function handleEquipmentMasterChanges(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = event.range;

  // Check if the changed range is in column "Kit Description"
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getSheet().getName() == "EQUIPMENT_MASTER") {
    var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EQUIPMENT_BOOKING");
    var targetColumn = targetSheet.getRange("A:A");

    // Delete or insert rows in EQUIPMENT_BOOKING based on changes in EQUIPMENT_MASTER
    if (range.getNumRows() > 1) {
      targetColumn.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, range.getNumRows() - 1);
    } else if (range.isBlank()) {
      var row = range.getRow();
      targetSheet.deleteRow(row);
    }

    // Copy "Kit Description" column with formatting to EQUIPMENT_BOOKING
    var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn(), range.getNumRows(), 1);
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    var sourceRichTextValues = sourceRange.getRichTextValues();
    var targetRange = targetColumn.offset(lastRow - 1, 0, range.getNumRows(), 1);
    targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);

    // Copy background colors from source range to target range
    var sourceBackgrounds = sourceRange.getBackgrounds();
    var targetBackgrounds = targetRange.getBackgrounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceBackgrounds.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < sourceBackgrounds[i].length; j++) {
        targetBackgrounds[i][j] = sourceBackgrounds[i][j];
      }
    }
    targetRange.setBackgrounds(targetBackgrounds);

    // Copy rich text values from source range to target range
    targetRange.setRichTextValues(sourceRichTextValues);
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Forgot to mention, both tabs are in the same spreadsheet and the trigger is manually created in the gui, not scripted

Comment: What is keeping you from debugging this problem?

Comment: In your question, you say `The OnSheetChange is run by an OnChange trigger.`. In this case, `event` of `onSheetChange(event)` has no property of `range`. By this, I think that an error occurs at `range.getColumn()` in `handleEquipmentMasterChanges`. But, you say `All the values and formatting are correctly copied, rows are deleted and inserted where necessary to reflect the changes`. From this situation, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your actual situation. How about this? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: in future try using `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to see what the event object looks like.  They are not all the same for all triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct, it turned out that it was running code from the trigger that had been deleted and code that had been deleted, so it seems I have an issue overwriting code